# Using window.scrollY for canvas calculations causes issues

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make a parallax-esque effect using HTML5 canvas, for various reasons. I've been using the window.scrollY property to determine how far down the user has scrolled and therefore can calculate the transformations using this value.

I suppose this is best explained through [an example](https://codepen.io/_mattrick/pen/yoMbRY):

```
function draw() {
  scrollOffset = window.scrollY;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect((width/2) - (size/2), ((height/2) - (size/2)) + scrollOffset, size, size);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

As you can see, depending on what browser you use, there will be a varying level of "glitchiness" caused by you scrolling. The square in the center should remain in the same place the entire time, however there are issues with keeping up with how far the user has scrolled.

How noticeable this problem is depends on what browser you are using; Chrome is only noticeable if you change your scrolling direction in rapid succession whereas Firefox and Edge are noticeable regardless of how slowly you scroll.

Would there be a better way to go about this?

Comment: JS based [Scroll-linked effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects) have problems like this because of asynchronous scrolling. Usually the solution is to use fixed position CSS.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara under normal circumstances, I would use `position: fixed`, but in my actual code I am doing an actual "parallax" effect (where the element won't be fixed but move with the page slowly) and I have multiple elements that will move at different rates.

Comment: Go look into setting `pointer-events:none` for all elements during scrolling, that is a common technique to get scroll-based effects to be smoother ...

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Not a solution but a suggestion

The parallax should happen only when one scrolls on the page. Should be something like the snippet below:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let width;
let height;

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);

function resizeCanvas() {
  width = canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  height = canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();

let scrollOffset;
let size = 50;

function draw() {
  scrollOffset = window.scrollY;  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect((width/2) - (size/2), ((height/2) - (size/2)) + scrollOffset, size, size);
}

draw();

window.onscroll = function (e)
{
    draw();
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
#padder {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<section id="padder"></section>
```

Also, since it's browser specific, for Firefox, check scrolling options in the advanced settings or you shall try changing the `mouseWheel` scrolling behavior in `about:config`

[image]